# Tips on using SQL access advisor in Oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, tuning

Please share how to use oracle SQL access adviser for single or multiple queries. you can assume that we know the sql ids for the queries we are interested in.

Comment: what did you already try?

Comment: I cant use a OEM and I read the article docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41573/advisor.htm. I am trying to find a source which has a simple example to use SQL Tuning advisor using the DBMS Advisor package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like:

```
declare
task varchar2(30);

begin
task:= dbms_sqltune.CREATE_TUNING_TASK ( sql_id => '&sql_id',
plan_hash_value => '&hv' );
dbms_output.put_line (task);
dbms_sqltune.execute_tuning_task(task);
end;
/
```

to get the job running.
List the tasks:

```
SELECT task_id, task_name, created, advisor_name, status
FROM dba_advisor_tasks
where TRUNC(created) = TRUNC(sysdate)
order by CREATEd desc;
```

when it is ready, read the report

```
SELECT DBMS_SQLTUNE.report_tuning_task('&tuning_task') AS recommendations FROM dual;
```

and if you want, implement recommendations:

```
DECLARE
-- accept plan profile
  l_sql_tune_task_id  VARCHAR2(20);
BEGIN
  l_sql_tune_task_id := DBMS_SQLTUNE.accept_sql_profile (
                          task_name => '&tuning_task',
                          name      => '&profile');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('l_sql_tune_task_id: ' || l_sql_tune_task_id);
END;
/
```

Reading the packages can help a lot.

For the SQL access advisor take a look at [SQL Access Advisor in Oracle Database](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/sql-access-advisor-10g.php)

Comment: Can you please provide a similar solution to use the SQL Access Advisor as you provided for tuning advisor. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, you are right. Thanks for the tip, I edited accordingly.

Comment: @Deven hmm, that's is quite a bit more complex. Parameters need to be added to the created task. Currently I have no example at hand. Check http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/sql-access-advisor-10g.php

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using inbuilt script .

**@?/rdbms/admin/sqltrpt.sql.**

It will display top 15 resource intensive SQL and prompt to enter the desire SQL_ID you want to tune.

You can even customize it to display the number of top SQL's .